# Redirect users from specific url via htaccess

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

Is it possible to redirect a user who is coming from a specific url to another url via htaccess or script? (htaccess prefered)

e.g.

user comes from www.domain-a.com/sample-site/ to www.domain-b.net/sample-site2/  and should be redirect to www.domain-c.org/sample3/
All other user shouldn’t be redirected only the users from www.domain-a.com/sample-site/

Domain-a and domain-b are wordpress sites.

Thanks for the help

Comment: Domain-a  and domain-b are under my control

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Assuming you have control over domain-b.net:

```
RewriteEngine on    
#If user clicks a link on a page sample-site of domain A
#which you may or may not control
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://(www.)?domain-a\.com/sample-site/? [NC]
#which aims at domain B, which you control, which runs this .htaccess file
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain-b.net$
#requesting page sample-site2
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/?sample-site2/?
#then rewrite to domain C page sample3
  RewriteRule ^ http://www.domain-c.org/sample3/ [R,L]
```

Comment: A and B belongs to me. I will try that and give a feedback. Thanks

Comment: ok, I insert that in my htaccess, but it doesn't work. I don't understand the line with {http_referer}. There is something wrong

Comment: RewriteEngine on    
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://(www.)?domain-a\.de/category/li-test/? [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain-b.net$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/?category/re-test/?
RewriteRule ^ http://www.domain-c.org/sample3/ [R,L]

Comment: Perhaps the HTTP_HOST in your link doesn't contain `www.`. Other than that, if you comment out the HTTP_REFERER line with a leading `#` does it work correctly?

Comment: ok, the problem was wp super cache with his rewrite rules - I solve that. The redirect works now, but it redirects the page (domain-b.net/category/re-test/) everytime, not only if someone klicks on the link on domain-a. I need only a redirect when someone comes from domain-a.de/category/li-test/. Now its a pemanent redirect.

Comment: Use `[R=302]`, a temporary redirect, not `[R=301]`, which is a permanent redirect. Make sure to clear your browser's cache, or use chrome's incognito mode, or test in another browser where your redirects aren't cached. Temp, 302, is the default if you don't specify a number.

Comment: you mean the last line like this? RewriteRule ^ http://www.domain-c.org/sample3/ [R=302,L] or where I need to insert [R=302]

Comment: `[R=302,L]` is the same as saying `[R,L]`, that won't make a different. My code is already fine and has been tested. In reply to your last sentence " Now its a pemanent redirect", If you have a permanent redirect happening in your browser cache from previously used code, then clear your cache. My code uses a temporary redirect, not a permanent redirect. Make sure you don't have other code conflicting with mine somewhere.

Comment: you are right, it was the cache. Now everything works fine and like I need it. Thank you very much for your help. Have a nice sunday.

Comment: The redirect works, but on http://www.whatismyreferer.com/ the referer is showing as domain-a not domain-b. Is there a way to solve that?

Comment: The behavior of all modern browsers that I know of is that the referer remains the same through redirects. If you need to change a header before preforming the redirect, you'd need to use a proxy.

Comment: Downvoter: Explain yourself. This is a good answer and deserves a positive rating.